# Nagios check_smb_status.sh

Tags: nagios

I am having a little issue here with this plugin. When run locally on the samba server machine it works fine:

**./check_smb_status.sh**

```
Total Users/Process:21 Total Machines:16 Total Files:67  |Total Users/Process=21 Total Machines=16 Total Files=67
```

But when run with NRPE plugin from the nagios server it's output is not correct:

**./check_nrpe -H  -t 500 -c check_smb_status**

```
Total Users/Process:0 Total Machines:0 Total Files:68  |Total Users/Process=0 Total Machines=0 Total Files=67
```

Here is the source of check_smb_status.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#    Program : check_smb_status
#            :
#    Purpose : Nagios plugin to return the number of user/processes into a smb
#            : server, total machines connected and the number of files open.
#            :
# Parameters : --help
#            : --version
#            :
#    Returns : Standard Nagios status_* codes as defined in utils.sh
#            :
#      Notes :
#============:==============================================================
#        1.0 : may/08/2011
#
PROGPATH=`/bin/echo $0 | /bin/sed -e 's,[\\/][^\\/][^\\/]*$,,'`
REVISION=`/bin/echo '$Revision: 1.0 $' | /bin/sed -e 's/[^0-9.]//g'`

SMBSTATUS_P="/tmp/smbstatus_p"
SMBSTATUS_L="/tmp/smbstatus_L"
/usr/bin/smbstatus -p > $SMBSTATUS_P 2> /dev/null
/usr/bin/smbstatus -L > $SMBSTATUS_L 2> /dev/null
    . $PROGPATH/utils.sh

    print_usage() {
            /bin/echo "Usage: $PROGNAME --help"
            /bin/echo "Usage: $PROGNAME --version"
    }

    print_help() {
            print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
            /bin/echo ""
            print_usage
            /bin/echo ""
            /bin/echo "Samba status check."
            /bin/echo ""
            support
    }


    if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
            print_usage
            exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
    fi


    exitstatus=$STATE_WARNING
    while test -n "$1"; do
            case "$1" in
                    --help)
                            print_help
                            exit $STATE_OK
                            ;;
                    -h)
                            print_help
                            exit $STATE_OK
                            ;;
                    --version)
                            print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
                            exit $STATE_OK
                            ;;
                    -V)
                            print_revision $PROGNAME $REVISION
                            exit $STATE_OK
                            ;;

                    *)
                            echo "Unknown argument: $1"
                            print_usage
                            exit $STATE_UNKNOWN
                            ;;
            esac
            shift
    done

    total_usersProcess=$(/bin/egrep "^([0-9]| +[0-9])" $SMBSTATUS_P | wc -l)

    total_files=$(/bin/egrep "^([0-9]| +[0-9])" $SMBSTATUS_L | wc -l)

    total_machines=$(/bin/egrep "^([0-9]| +[0-9])" $SMBSTATUS_P | awk '{print $5}' | sort -u | wc -l)


    /bin/echo "Total Users/Process:$total_usersProcess Total Machines:$total_machines Total Files:$total_files  |Total Users/Process=$total_usersProcess Total Machines=$total_machines Total Files=$total_files"

    /bin/rm -f $SMBSTATUS_P $SMBSTATUS_L

    exit $STATE_OK
```

Comment: Please post the source of `check_smb_status.sh`, and the `check_smb_status` routine in your Nagios configuration.

Comment: User permissions?  Try running it locally as the 'nrpe' user.

Answer (score 0):

It's because nagios user cannot access files.
You can do: `chmod 666 /var/lib/samba/*.tdb`, or `646` if you think `666` is too devilish.

Of course, you must keep in mind, that this is a security risk.
And with a great samba power, comes great responsibility :)

Answer (score 0):

The program `smbstatus` need to be executed by root.

Add to the `/etc/sudoers.d/nrpe`:

```
user_running_nrpe ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /plugins_path/check_smb_status.sh
```

And in the `nrpe.cfg`:

```
command[check_smb_status.sh]=/usr/bin/sudo /plugins_path/check_smb_status.sh
```

If you have selinux activated check the context of the file `/plugins_path/check_smb_status.sh`.

Also there is a problem with the script, when "samba" is stopped, the script return it is ok so add the line below before `exit $STATE_OK`:

```
echo | /usr/bin/smbclient -L localhost >/dev/null 2>&1 || exit $STATE_CRITICAL
```